# What is the best way to write an int array (image data) to file

Tags: java, android

I have a large int array containing image data in the format ARGB (alpha, R, G and B channels, 1 byte each). I want to save it to file in `onPause()` to be able to reload it when the app is restarted. What do you think is the best way to do that?

I found the following methods:

- Convert the int array to a byte array manually (see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/intarraytobytearray.htm)) and then use a `FileOutputStream` to output the byte array.
- Wrap the array into a `java.nio.IntBuffer` and then write the object to file using `java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`.
- Write each element one at a time using `java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeInt()`.

All these methods seem quite wasteful so there is probably another, better way. Possibly even a way to use image compression to reduce the size of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those. Some of them don't even make sense.

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
```

then call `dos.writeInt()` as many times as necessary, then close `dos`. The buffer will take away most of the pain.

Or else create an `IntBuffer` and use `FileChannel.write()`, but I've never been able to figure out how that works in the absence of an `IntBuffer.asByteBuffer()` method. Or else create a `ByteBuffer`, take it as an `IntBuffer` via `asIntBuffer()`, put the data in, then adjust the `ByteBuffer`'s length, which is another missing piece of the API, and again use `FileChannel.write(ByteBuffer)`.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view you can also use android specific storages

1. Use database/content provider for storing image data
2. Use out Bundle in `onSaveInstance` method

If your still want to write to a file you can use following NIO based code:

```
static void writeIntArray(int[] array) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out.file");
    try {
        ByteBuffer byteBuff = ByteBuffer.allocate((Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE) * array.length);
        IntBuffer intBuff = byteBuff.asIntBuffer();
        intBuff.put(array);
        intBuff.flip();
        FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
        fc.write(byteBuff);
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried with onSaveInstance but ran into a weird problem. Using the sequence Home Button -> Restart App -> Close screen (pressing the power button) -> Restore (power button again), onCreate() is called once with a null bundle, onSaveInstance is called, then onCreate() is called again. The result is that the data in the bundle is lost. This only seems to appear if the processing in onSaveInstance() is long and the app is set as android:screenOrientation="landscape".